# Personalizar estructura de Json Laravel

Tags: laravel, json, vuejs

Estoy aprendiendo de Vuejs, adquirí un *template* ya listo con un starter-kit para iniciar en el desarrollo, el problema es que mi json no tiene la estructura que requiere el componente, es decir encierra los datos dentro de parametros que no sé como pasarlos para que queden así:

El componente requiere los datos en un Json así:

```
pages: {
    key: "title",
    data: [
      {title: 'Home',   url: '/',      icon: 'HomeIcon', is_bookmarked: true},
      {title: 'Page 2', url: '/page2', icon: 'FileIcon', is_bookmarked: false},
    ]
  }
```

Pero laravel los exporta de esta forma:

```
{
    current_page: 1,
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        user_id: '1',
        title: 'Home',
        url: '/app/home',
        icon: 'HomeIcon',
        is_bookmarked: 'false',
        created_at: '2019-12-22 11:35:57',
        updated_at: '2019-12-22 11:35:59'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        user_id: '1',
        title: 'Users',
        url: '/app/user/user-list',
        icon: 'UserIcon',
        is_bookmarked: 'false',
        created_at: '2019-12-22 11:37:44',
        updated_at: '2019-12-22 11:37:46'
      }
    ],
    first_page_url: 'http://emplenio.test/api/v1/pages?page=1',
    from: 1,
    last_page: 1,
    last_page_url: 'http://emplenio.test/api/v1/pages?page=1',
    next_page_url: null,
    path: 'http://emplenio.test/api/v1/pages',
    per_page: 15,
    prev_page_url: null,
    to: 2,
    total: 2
}
```

Aún con esta estructura puedo visualizar los datos desde la herramienta de desarollo de Vuejs para chrome, más no los enlista porque la estructura no es la correcta y me arroja el error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array
```

[aqui](https://ibb.co/5KFPrZd) dejo un screen de como deberia recibir los datos el componente
y [Aqui](https://ibb.co/0BNthVZ) como los esta recibiendo

El código del controlador de la api es el siguiente:

```
class NavbarSearchAndPinlistController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $query = NavbarSearchAndPinlist::where('user_id', '1');
        $pages = $query->paginate();
        if(request()->wantsJson())
        {
            return $pages;
        }
        return view('partials.failed');
    }
}
```

y el del complemento es así:

```
<script>
import VxAutoSuggest from '@/components/vx-auto-suggest/VxAutoSuggest.vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  components: {
    VxAutoSuggest
  },
  data() {
    return {
      navbarSearchAndPinList: [],
      showFullSearch: false,
    }
  },
    mounted(){
        axios.get('/api/v1/pages')
            .then(res => {
                this.navbarSearchAndPinList = res.data.data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

    },
  methods: {
    selected(item) {
      item.pages ?  this.$router.push(item.pages.url).catch(() => {}) : null
      this.showFullSearch = false;
    },
    hnd_search_query_update(query) {
      // Show overlay if any character is entered
      this.$store.commit('TOGGLE_CONTENT_OVERLAY', query ? true : false)
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a resolverlo, gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad que le pasas a `vxAutosuggest`, como dices, debe ser un objeto con la forma:

```
{
  title: 'Título',
  data: [{elemento1},{elemento2}]
}
```

Cuando asignas

```
this.navbarSearchAndPinList = res.data.data;
```

El componente recibe

```
[{elemento1}, {elemento2}]
```

La solución sería asignar, en cambio:

```
this.navbarSearchAndPinList = {titulo:'Título', data: res.data.data};
```

Comment: Gracias! funciono, con algunas pequeñas modificaciones pero tu respuesta me ayudo demasiado, gracias bro